# multiple messages through a pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am trying to send two messages "hello World" and "Goodbye" from parent to a child using a pipe. The child must print the messages when recieves them.
My problem is how to send the second message. I compile and run the program but it only prints the first message. Any sugestions?
Here's my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 50

void main(){

    int fd[2], n, status;
    char buf[MAX];
    pid_t pid;
    char str1[]="Hello World!\n";
    char str2[]="Goodbye\n";
    pipe(fd);

    if((pid=fork())<0){
        abort();
    }

    else if(pid>0){// parent code goes here
        close (fd[0]); // close read channel of parent

        /*Send "hello world" through the pipe*/

        write(fd[1],str1,(strlen(str1))); // write to the pipe

        wait(&status);

        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1],str2,(strlen(str2)));
    }  
    else{ // child code goes here
        close(fd[1]); // close write channel of child

        n=read(fd[0], buf, sizeof(buf)); // reads from the pipe
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you closing `fd[0]` twice in the parent?

Comment: `wait` waits for the child to exit. Why are you trying to write something to the pipe after the child has finished and won't try to read it?

Comment: The second close makes no sense, you're right. my mistake
I Was trying to wait for the child to end to write again on pipe, but i dont really know if that is correct.  :/

Comment: suggest enabling all the warnings when compiling.  then 'void main()' would be corrected to 'int main(void)'  and the header file 'sys/types.h' would have been included so 'pid_t' would be defined.

Comment: regarding the line: 'wait(&status)' waits for the child to exit, while capturing the the exit status/value.  Probably NOT what what you want to do.  Why is the code closing fd[0] more that once?  a 'pipe' does not know about EOF, records, nor any kind of formatting.  the code that reads the pipe needs to take that into account,

Answer (score 3):

In the parent, just write the two messages and then close the write end of the pipe:

```
close(fd[0]); // close read channel of pipe in parent
write (fd[1], str1, strlen(str1)); // write "hello world"
write (fd[1], str2, strlen(str2)); // write "goodbye"
close(fd[1]); // Tell child that we're done writing

wait(&status); // Wait for child to read everything and exit
```

In the child, you should read in a loop until you get EOF, indicated by `read()` returning 0:

```
close(fd[1]); // close write channel of pipe in child
while ((n = read(fd[0], buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0) { // Read until it returns 0 (EOF) or -1 (error)
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
}
if (n < 0) { // -1 = error
    perror("read from pipe");
}
```

Comment: Yeah it Works! Thanks a lot!!! but i didn't understand the while condition. Is n an integer? what's the meaning of n? what is the value that read function gives to n?

Comment: It's the number of bytes that were read. You used it in your own program, so how can you not know what it is?

Comment: I had an ideia, just to make sure i was not wrong! Thanks a lot. :)